Show that $w_1 = w_2$
In my machine learning class, we have been assigned to show the equality between $w_1$ and $w_2$, where they are defined like this:
$$
w_1 = (XX^T+\gamma I)^{-1}Xy, \in \Re^D \\
w_2=X(X^TX+\gamma I)^{-1}y, \in \Re^D
$$
$$
X_{DxN} \\ X^T_{NxD} \\ I_{NxN} \text{ in $w_2$} \\ I_{DxD} \text{ in $w_2$}
$$
How do you show this equality?
I have attempted to use the woodbury identity matrix, but I have gotten stuck in that process. Starting from $w_1$:
$$(XX^T+\gamma I)^{−1}Xy=\gamma I−\gamma IX((X^T)^{−1}+X^T\gamma IX)^{−1}X^T\gamma I$$

kindly include your attempt.

@SiongThyeGoh
I have attempted to use the woodbury identity matrix, but I have gotten stuck in that process.
Starting from w1
$$
(XX^T+\gamma I)^{-1}Xy = \gamma I - \gamma IX((X^T)^{-1}+X^T\gamma IX)^{-1}X^T \gamma I
$$

You want to show that
$$(XX^T+\gamma I_N)^{-1}Xy=X(X^TX+\gamma I_D)^{-1}y$$
This is equivalent to showing that
$$Xy=(XX^T+\gamma I_n)X(X^TX+\gamma I_D)^{-1}y$$
Let's work out from RHS:
$$(XX^T+\gamma I_n)X(X^TX+\gamma I_D)^{-1}y=(XX^TX+\gamma X)(X^TX+\gamma I_D)^{-1}y=X(X^TX+\gamma I_D)(X^TX+\gamma I_D)^{-1}y$$
Can you complete the task?
